# In Verilog, is it possible to check the conditions of a loop after executing the logic?

Tags: loops, verilog

Effectively, I'm looking for a way to loop 8 times using only a 3-bit variable for incrementation.

I do realise that a simple solution is to use a 4-bit variable and use

```
for(i=0; i<8; i = i+1)
```

But if it is possible to check the conditions of a loop only after executing its contents, then a solution like the following (which is written in SystemVerilog using do...while) can be written.

```
  initial begin
    reg [2:0] i = 3'b000;    
    do begin 
      $display("i = %g", i);
      i++;
    end while (i !== 3'b000);
  end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do..while` construct exists in **system verilog** and the soulution you showed works there. It does not work in plain verilog though.

For plain verilog you can use any programming trick to do so, i.e. use a flag:

```
  reg [2:0] i;
  reg flag;

  initial begin
    flag = 0;
    i = 0;
    while(flag == 0) begin
      $display("i = %g", i);
      i = i+1;
      if (i == 0) flag = 1;
    end
  end
```

you can unroll one iteration manually:

```
  initial begin
   i = 0;
   $display("i = %g", i);
   i = 1;
   while( i != 0) begin
      $display("i = %g", i);
      i = i+1;
    end
  end
```

you can use repeat:

```
  initial begin
    i = 0;
    repeat(8) begin
      $display("i = %g", i);
      i = i+1;
    end
  end
```

and so on.